# which statement best describes the linear correlation

Tags: calculus, statistics

Over the course of a given week, 39 members of a reading club went to the library

The table below shoes the ages of these 39 members and the number of time they visited the library that week

[image]

Which one of the following statements best describes the linear correlation between the ages of the members and the number of library visits?

a) the correlation is positive and high

b) the correlation is positive and low

c) the correlation is negative and high

d) the correlation is negative and low

I don't understand how to solve this question just by looking at the table. 
Do i draw a scatter plot? but we don't have ordered pairs (x,y)

Answer (score 1):

You have $39$ ordered pairs of the form $\langle\text{age},\text{number of visits}\rangle$; $2$ of them are $\langle 13,3\rangle$, $6$ of them are $\langle 13,5\rangle$, and so on. Thus, you could indeed draw a scatter-plot. But you probably don’t really need to, if you look carefully at the table. Where are the largest entries? $6$ of the seven $16$-year-olds went just once, $8$ of the ten $15$-year-olds went two or three times, $4$ of the nine $14$-year-olds went four times, and $6$ of the ten $13$-year-olds went $5$ times. What kind of correlation does that look like?